# Return all rows in MySQL LEFT JOIN query (table self-join)

Tags: mysql, self-join

I have the following hierarchical table structure "**nato**" in MySQL 8:

```
INSERT INTO `nato`(`id`, `parentID`, `level`, `name`, `has_children`) VALUES (1, NULL, 0, 'Charlie', 1);
INSERT INTO `nato`(`id`, `parentID`, `level`, `name`, `has_children`) VALUES (2, NULL, 0, 'Echo', 1);
INSERT INTO `nato`(`id`, `parentID`, `level`, `name`, `has_children`) VALUES (3, 1, 1, 'Alpha', 0);
INSERT INTO `nato`(`id`, `parentID`, `level`, `name`, `has_children`) VALUES (4, 1, 1, 'Tango', 1);
INSERT INTO `nato`(`id`, `parentID`, `level`, `name`, `has_children`) VALUES (5, 2, 1, 'Papa', 1);
INSERT INTO `nato`(`id`, `parentID`, `level`, `name`, `has_children`) VALUES (6, 1, 1, 'Foxtrot', 1);
INSERT INTO `nato`(`id`, `parentID`, `level`, `name`, `has_children`) VALUES (7, NULL, 0, 'Uniform', 0);
INSERT INTO `nato`(`id`, `parentID`, `level`, `name`, `has_children`) VALUES (8, 2, 1, 'Lima', 0);
INSERT INTO `nato`(`id`, `parentID`, `level`, `name`, `has_children`) VALUES (9, 4, 2, 'Sierra', 0);
INSERT INTO `nato`(`id`, `parentID`, `level`, `name`, `has_children`) VALUES (10, 5, 2, 'Juliet', 0);
INSERT INTO `nato`(`id`, `parentID`, `level`, `name`, `has_children`) VALUES (11, 6, 2, 'India', 0);
INSERT INTO `nato`(`id`, `parentID`, `level`, `name`, `has_children`) VALUES (12, 6, 2, 'Oscar', 0);
```

(***What I have:***)

```
id   parentID    level    name        has_children
1     (null)       0      Charlie           1
2     (null)       0      Echo              1
3         1        1      Alpha             0
4         1        1      Tango             1
5         2        1      Papa              1
6         1        1      Foxtrot           1
7     (null)       0      Uniform           0
8         2        1      Lima              0
9         4        2      Sierra            0
10        5        2      Juliet            0
11        6        2      India             0
12        6        2      Oscar             0
```

against which I am running the following query, where L0 is level 0, etc: (***What I tried:***)

```
SELECT f.id    AS L0_id,
       f.NAME  AS L0_name,
       f1.id   AS L1_id,
       f1.NAME AS L1_name,
       f2.id   AS L2_id,
       f2.NAME AS L2_name
FROM   nato f
LEFT JOIN nato f1
    ON f1.parentID = f.id
LEFT JOIN nato f2
    ON f2.parentID = f1.id
WHERE  f.parentID IS NULL
ORDER  BY l0_id ASC
```

to obtain the result across the levels "L0" to "L2": (***What I got:***)

```
L0_id       L0_name     L1_id     L1_name     L2_id     L2_name
  1         Charlie       3       Alpha        (null)   (null)
  1         Charlie       4       Tango         9       Sierra
  1         Charlie       6       Foxtrot       11      India
  1         Charlie       6       Foxtrot       12      Oscar
  2         Echo          5       Papa          10      Juliet
  2         Echo          8       Lima         (null)   (null)
  7         Uniform    (null)     (null)       (null)   (null)
```

What I would have liked to obtain is one row for each of the items with children as well (similar to the row for Uniform), in increasing order of id i.e. (***What I expected to get***)

```
L0_id       L0_name     L1_id     L1_name     L2_id     L2_name
  1         Charlie     (null)    (null)       (null)   (null)
  1         Charlie       3       Alpha        (null)   (null)
  1         Charlie       4       Tango        (null)   (null)
  1         Charlie       4       Tango         9       Sierra
  1         Charlie       6       Foxtrot      (null)   (null)
  1         Charlie       6       Foxtrot       11      India
  1         Charlie       6       Foxtrot       12      Oscar
  2         Echo        (null)     (null)       (null)   (null)
  2         Echo          4       Papa         (null)   (null)
  2         Echo          5       Papa          10      Juliet
  2         Echo          8       Lima         (null)   (null)
  7         Uniform    (null)     (null)       (null)   (null)
```

How do I modify my query to achieve the above result? I already added two columns (**level** and **has_children**) if that will makes things easier, but I am still not sure how to achieve my goal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check again your sample data and expected results. Where does Admin come from? Also `4 Papa`.

Comment: Sorry, autocomplete in my text editor, plus a repeated copy and paste error. It should be Alpha. The SQL query is working fine, I just can't get those extra rows to show up.

Comment: @Cogicero Can you provide a fiddle link?

Comment: I just answered my own question, probably not the best query but I am on an awfully tight deadline. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I cobbled up eventually, using two UNIONs. Most probably not the most effective way, but I hope it helps someone else.

```
SELECT
        f.id as L_id,
        f.name as L_name,
        f1.id as L1_id,
        f1.name as L1_name,
        f2.id as L2_id,
        f2.name as L2_name
FROM
        nato f
LEFT JOIN nato f1
        ON f1.parentID = f.id
LEFT JOIN nato f2
        ON f2.parentID = f1.id
WHERE
        f.parentID IS NULL
UNION
   SELECT f.id as L_id,
            f.name as L_name,
            NULL as L1_id,
            NULL as L1_name,
            NULL as L2_name,
            NULL as L2_name
        FROM nato f
                 WHERE f.parentID IS NULL
                 AND f.has_children = 1
UNION
   SELECT f.id as L_id,
            f.name as L_name,
            f1.id as L1_id,
            f1.name as L1_name,
            NULL as L2_name,
            NULL as L2_name
        FROM nato f
        LEFT JOIN nato f1
             ON f1.parentID = f.id
                 WHERE f.parentID IS NULL
                 AND f1.has_children = 1
ORDER BY
        L_id,L1_id,L2_id ASC
```

Yielding the results as expected:

```
L_id       L_name     L1_id     L1_name     L2_id     L2_name
  1         Charlie     (null)    (null)       (null)   (null)
  1         Charlie       3       Alpha        (null)   (null)
  1         Charlie       4       Tango        (null)   (null)
  1         Charlie       4       Tango         9       Sierra
  1         Charlie       6       Foxtrot      (null)   (null)
  1         Charlie       6       Foxtrot       11      India
  1         Charlie       6       Foxtrot       12      Oscar
  2         Echo        (null)     (null)       (null)   (null)
  2         Echo          4       Papa         (null)   (null)
  2         Echo          5       Papa          10      Juliet
  2         Echo          8       Lima         (null)   (null)
  7         Uniform    (null)     (null)       (null)   (null)
```